# Strange sorting by text column on Ubuntu

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

It's the biggest surprise on the part of Postgres I've ever had to deal with. I made this simple test on ubuntu 14.04:

```
postgres=# select version();
                                                    version                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.0 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55), 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# create table test (val text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into test values ('a'), ('b'), ('-a'), ('-b');
INSERT 0 4
postgres=# select * from test order by val;
 val 
-----
 a
 -a
 b
 -b
(4 rows)
```

Obviously this is not what can be considered correct. A similar result can be seen on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/34f57/1) that uses

```
PostgreSQL version 9.3.6 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2, 64-bit
```

The same test on Windows servers

```
PostgreSQL 9.4.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
PostgreSQL 9.1.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1500, 32-bit
```

gives the correct result:

```
postgres=# select version();
                           version
-------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.0, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit
(1 row)

postgres=# create table test (val text);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into test values ('a'), ('b'), ('-a'), ('-b');
INSERT 0 4
postgres=# select * from test order by val;
 val
-----
 -a
 -b
 a
 b
(4 rows)
```

I do not know how to deal with it. I need a stable server on Ubuntu, but now lost confidence in this version. Ubuntu users, please make the test and share the results. Any tips would be appreciated of course.

---

Thanks to Simo I found out what follows.
Postgres has only two built-in collations: C and POSIX. Any other collations are provided by operating system.
Postgres 9.3 server on sqlfiddle uses `lc_collate = en_US.utf8` and my server uses `pl_PL.utf8`, what means the collations are provided by Ubuntu. To check it out I ran *sort* on terminal and obtained the same results:

```
me@ubu:~$ sort
a
b
-a
-b

a
-a
b
-b
```

Now I know the culprit, but it still does not solve my problem.

Comment: What does `SHOW lc_collate` give? Collations would be the settings that define the sort order - [PostgreSQL Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/collation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you will probably have to accept this. In short, on GNU systems in UTF locales all non alphanumeric characters are ignored during sorting. You can find more detailed explanation [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87763).

Answer (score 2):

> my
>   server uses pl_PL.utf8, what means the collations are provided by
>   Ubuntu

Yes, but this can be overriden in various ways.

- An individual expression can be assigned a collation, which is particularly relevant in an `ORDER BY` clause. If you use:

  ```
  select * from test order by val COLLATE "C";
  ```

  This will sort as what is to you the "correct result", independently of `lc_collate`.
- An individual column can also be assigned a collation so that it doesn't have to be explicitly mentioned in every sort or comparison:

  ```
   create table test (val text COLLATE "C");
  ```
- A database can also be assigned a collation that differs from the server's default, see `LC_COLLATE` clause in [CREATE DATABASE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html).

See [Collation support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html) in PostgreSQL manual for more.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, thanks. I have already found this solution but collation "C" ignores special order positions of diacritics. My goal is to find a solution on Ubuntu that is compatible with Windows. Now I think about whether I can define my own collation on Ubuntu.